# Yii2 rest api join query with ActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a custom action in ActiveController and need to fetch some data by joining two tables.
I have written following query .

```
$query = Item::find()->joinWith(['subcategory'])->select(['item.*', 'sub_category.name'])->where(['item.active' => 1])->addOrderBy(['item.id' => SORT_DESC]);

    $pageSize = (isset($_GET["limit"]) ? $_GET["limit"] : 1) * 10;
    $page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query, 'pagination' => ['pageSize' => $pageSize, "page" => $page]]);
    $formatter = new ResponseFormatter();
    return $formatter->formatResponse("", $dataProvider->getTotalCount(), $dataProvider->getModels());
```

but it is throwing an exception

```
"message": "Setting unknown property: common\\models\\Item::name",
```

Here is the item Model with all the fields and relation.

```
    <?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\BaseActiveRecord;
use yii\db\Expression;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "item".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $subcategory_id
 * @property string $title
 * @property resource $description
 * @property integer $created_by
 * @property integer $updated_by
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 * @property string $image
 * @property integer $active
 *
 * @property SubCategory $subcategory
 */
class Item extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $imageFile;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'item';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['created_by', 'updated_by'], 'required'],
            [['subcategory_id', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'active'], 'integer'],
            [['description'], 'string'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['title', 'image'], 'string', 'max' => 999],
            [['title'], 'unique'],
            [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'subcategory_id' => 'Subcategory ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'created_by' => 'Created By',
            'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
            'image' => 'Image',
            'active' => 'Active',
            'imageFile' => 'Image',
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSubcategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SubCategory::className(), ['id' => 'subcategory_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'created_by']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUpdatedBy()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'updated_by']);
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_at',
                ],
                'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess your Item model does not have a variable $name declared.

Comment: yes It doesn't have, name belongs to Subcategory.

Comment: show you Item model please

Comment: All the code please  i don't see the relations  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joinWith makes a query using the joins requested, but result data are mapped in source model (in this case Item).

Since you have `select(['item.*', 'sub_category.name'])` , the framework will try to fill 'name' field of Item model, that does not exist and this generates the error.

According with documentation (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#overriding-extra-fields) you should have db relation **subcategory** populated from db, by default, but I don't see **subcategory** relation in your model.

So you have only to create **subcategory** relation in your model, such as:

```
public function getSubcategory() { return $this->hasOne(Subcategory::className(), ['id' => 'subcategory_id']); }
```

So you should solve your problem.

Other solution to have custom fields from more models could be:

1) Create a sql View (and from that create the Model) with fields that you want and pass it to ActiveDataProvide

2) Override `extraFields` method of the model (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-arrayabletrait.html#extraFields%28%29-detail)

Again, I suggest you to read this good article:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/834/relational-query-eager-loading-in-yii-2-0/